# Drupal 7 displaying image in search results

Tags: drupal, search

I have a content type called "people".  When a search is made and one of the search results is of "people" type, I want to display two fields of the "people" type; an image called "photo", and a text filed called "email".

Under "Manage Display" of the "people" content type, I selected custom display types and selected "Search Result" box.  After saving, I selected the new "Search result" button and hid all other fields except "photo" and "email".  I then customized the photo to have image style of "thumbnail".

I saved, cleared the cache, and reindexed the site.  The search results are correct but no images are shown.  I am very new to Drupal, all the help I could find is for Drupal 6 and by reading the comments people say that the solutions shown do not work for Drupal 7.  Help...

Comment: first comment is the answer on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14471/drupal-7-displaying-an-image-to-search-results. hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module which will further augment what you are trying to achieve and probably work better for you.

Here is a [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn3e91C_2jw&list=PL7E361A55994F1648&index=5&feature=plpp_video) about the search results specifically